# execute php files without typing php in front

Tags: php

Anyone can assist me on how to execute my php files without preceding php front
Examples instead of typing 'php filename.php' in cli or cloud9

I want to execute them by just typing the file name

command: 'filename'

then the script runs

Well i was thinking of using the htaccess file but i'm not sure if that also works on vps or cli. I know of browser only

Comment: Why do you want do to this?

Comment: look at  [shebang](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang) to get started.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, Alright will check for that, I hope you do understand what i mean?

Comment: @AlesiaThiel yep, your question was perfectly clear to me. I do that often in some of my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your PHP script and add this as the new first line, by itself, before your opening `<?php` tag:

```
#!/path/to/php
```

(Replace that with your actual path.)

Alternatively, if you have the `env` command, you can use that to figure it out for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

So your script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo "Hello, world!\n";
```

Then make the file exectuable:

```
chmod u+x filename
```

Now you can just "run" it directly in the shell:

```
% filename
Hello, world!
```

Note, you only want to do this if the script is CLI-only. If it's ever run via the web server, that first line will be output to the browser.

Comment: it says this : bash: ./filename: /usr/bin/php^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Its worked,  i added this command , sed -i -e 's/\r$//' filename.php    . Thank you